# Subdomains using CNAMEs, what record types are valid?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I know that if I have a website hosted on one sub-domain, I can create an alias sub-domain using CNAME records with the following setup:

```
subdomain.primary.com
A 50.50.50.50

subdomain.vanity.com
CNAME subdomain.primary.com
```

The thing I am not sure about is whether DNS record types, other than A records, will be redirected.  For example:

```
subdomain.primary.com
A 50.50.50.50
MX 1 50.50.50.51
MX 2 50.50.50.52
TXT some text string

subdomain.vanity.com
CNAME subdomain.primary.com
```

Will `subdomain.vanity.com` inherit all DNS records from `subdomain.primary.com`?

What if there is a sub-domain of `subdomain.primary.com`?  In my case, I am looking at setting up DKIM records:

```
k0._domainkey.subdomain.primary.com
TXT k=rsa...
```

Will `subdomain.vanity.com` inherit all of those records too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A canonical name `CNAME` record states that `subdomain.vanity.com` is basically an alias of `subdomain.primary.com`, so this will affect all query types. There's no reason to believe that it would be specific to `A` queries, that's just its most common use.

The `CNAME` record only applies to `subdomain.vanity.com` though.

Comment: What about the `_domainkey` subdomain?  It looks like Sendgrid is adding another CNAME record.  I did not know that was legal. http://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/whitelabel_wizard.html

Comment: @dana simply adding more dotted words to the beginning of a DNS record does not mean it is a subdomain, though that term has been co-opted and corrupted by many hosting companies. `this.is.simply.a.long.hostname.domain.com` 
A true DNS sub-domain will actually delegate responsibility for DNS lookups for the sub-domain to another set of DNS servers entirely

Comment: One DNS resource can only have 1 CNAME. Having more than one (or a CNAME and other records, other than DNSSEC) makes no sense. Looking at the Sendgrid page, they show 3 CNAME records to add, but each one is for a different resource (location as they call it in the table)

Comment: Thanks for the comments :) I learned some interesting stuff here.

Answer (score -1):

No. The CNAME record is nothing but an alias to an A record. It does not inherit nor affect any other record or lookup.

If you want A/MX/TXT records for subdomain.vanity.com you will have to define them separately.

#### edit:

In the case of the DKIM records the answer is a little fuzzier. Messages sent by a server with DKIM set up to sign messages with primary.com's DKIM *can* sign messages sent via the vanity.com domain, but the DKIM signature will refer to primary.com as the DKIM signer so that receiving servers will look up the correct key.